# How to make a 3D surface/contour Plot from 2 categorical variables & 1 numeric?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

**Describing my dataset:**

A have a dataset similar to this in which I have a data-frame of 3 columns, 2 are factors that describe the progression of a dialogue as students communicate with each other (`Discourse Code`) and construct models through words (`Modeling Code`) over a period of about 30 minutes (`Time_Processed`). Altogether, I have a data-frame of about (386 rows x 9 columns), but I'm sharing here a random sample of about 100 rows for confidentiality.

The `Discourse Code` have factors such as the following:

```
"AG"  "C"   "D"   "DA"  "G"   "J"   "OFF" "Q"   "S"
```

And the `Modeling Code` has factors such as these:

```
"A"   "MA"  "OFF" "P"   "SM"  "V"
```

And the `Time_Processed` is just numeric minutes like:

```
3.4500 11.2500 12.2500 14.4667 17.9333 18.0167 18.0667 18.6333 32.9000 33.1333, etc ...
```

I was trying to construct a surface plot with ggplot2 , but the fact that I had so many more time data-points than I could fit into (6 x 9) or (9 x 6) matrix makes it rather hard to construct surface plot.

If you consider the popular volcano dataset distributed with R,
if you melt it down, then you accurately get the corresponding frequencies on a volcano, actually, because that's what it models:

```
 library(dplyr)
    reshape2::melt(volcano) %>% head
      Var1 Var2 value
    1    1    1   100 # x = row 1, y = column 1, z = 100
    2    2    1   101 # x = row 2, y = column 2, z = 101,
    3    3    1   102 # etc ... 
    4    4    1   103
    5    5    1   104
    6    6    1   105
    etc ...
```

All those coordinates match up well to this plot_ly plot and you get a third dimension "z" which is each value in that large matrix corresponding to (x,y) coordinate pairs. This type of plot is just two variables: rows, columns, with the height z being the matrix of those.

```
plot_ly(z = ~ volcano) %>% add_surface()
```

[image: Volcano Plot]

More Interactive Version Here: https://plot.ly/r/3d-surface-plots/

That kind of plot is too simple for my case. I don't have 2-3 numerical values.

My dataset looks like this:

```
 `Modeling Code` `Discourse Code`      Time_Processed
 1 SM              J                          5.05
 2 OFF             OFF                        6.95
 3 P               Q                          3.18
 4 MA              S                         20.4 
 5 MA              S                         20.6 
 6 A               S                         32.7 
 7 V               S                         17.8 
 8 MA              S                         20.5 
 9 V               J                          8.05
10 MA              C                         14.4
```

etc ... 
More accurately it's this:

```
df <- structure(list(`Modeling Code` = structure(c(5L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 
    2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
    2L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 
    1L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 
    3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 
    6L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 2L
    ), .Label = c("A", "MA", "OFF", "P", "SM", "V"), class = "factor"), 
        `Discourse Code` = structure(c(6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
        9L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 9L, 8L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 9L, 2L, 9L, 1L, 6L, 
        7L, 8L, 8L, 6L, 4L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 7L, 9L, 1L, 1L, 9L, 
        2L, 1L, 2L, 8L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 9L, 3L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 1L, 5L, 7L, 
        1L, 3L, 9L, 6L, 3L, 9L, 9L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 8L, 9L, 2L, 4L, 
        3L, 7L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 7L, 2L, 2L, 8L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 9L, 6L, 
        4L, 8L, 8L, 1L, 8L, 2L, 9L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 7L, 
        6L, 4L, 8L), .Label = c("AG", "C", "D", "DA", "G", "J", "OFF", 
        "Q", "S"), class = "factor"), Time_Processed = c(5.05, 6.95, 
        3.1833, 20.4333, 20.55, 32.7333, 17.75, 20.5167, 8.05, 14.3667, 
        20.7167, 15.4833, 4, 26.2667, 14.6667, 17.2167, 33.1833, 
        3.1, 18.9833, 9.35, 17.35, 30.7167, 23.1167, 18.1667, 27.1833, 
        26.4667, 3.7, 20.5, 23.0833, 24.6833, 22.8833, 7.8333, 10.3, 
        24.8, 26.5, 26.1667, 15.05, 15.6, 3.8, 24.8, 5.6, 27.0833, 
        32.6667, 32.0167, 3.0333, 2.1667, 12.7167, 32.6167, 22.6, 
        24.25, 1.4333, 28.6333, 9.9667, 3.45, 32.7, 12.9667, 6.25, 
        30.3, 9.9, 16.9667, 20.8667, 3.6, 16.3833, 26.7, 13.55, 23.45, 
        11.4167, 17.55, 19.6333, 3.05, 11.35, 26.8, 12.85, 10.15, 
        26.6667, 4.6, 15.8667, 15.7333, 9.5167, 27.7667, 13.95, 23.9833, 
        15.6333, 6.9, 4.4833, 17.1167, 12.25, 24.7833, 17.0833, 13.9, 
        11.85, 29, 10.2667, 20.8167, 17.0333, 13.3167, 27.8, 8.55, 
        27.2, 21.2167)), .Names = c("Modeling Code", "Discourse Code", 
    "Time_Processed"), row.names = c(NA, -100L), class = c("tbl_df", 
    "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Since I know some mathematics and I can get get a countour plot to work in R, I know that I  can display The time as contour plot  for each discourse code and modeling code where `Time_Processed` has heat:

```
plot_ly(data = df, x = ~ `Modeling Code`, y = ~ `Discourse Code`, z = ~ `Time_Processed`, type = "contour") # if I try %>% add_surface() to this then I get z must be a numeric matrix
```

[image: Contour Plot]

This is contour plot is kind of telling. It's like looking at a mountain range from the sky. The hot values (yellow) are higher up in the sky, and the cold values (blue) are valleys or at the base of the mountains.

*So my question is how can make this contour plot have a "Time_Processed" height component to it and I can better visualize the heat of "Time_Processed" by looking at my graph in 3 dimensions?*

The fact that I can make a contour plot means that my  3 variable data should be  presentable in 3 dimensions. This is what that volcano would look like as a contour plot.

```
plot_ly(z = ~ volcano, type = "contour")
```

[image: contour of a volcano]

It's easy to see that this is a volcano from the contour plot. My data is less pretty, but if I trace the 3D surface with respect to `Time_Processed`, then I could get a good idea of the problem solving and communication techniques that my subjects are implementing over time.

It doesn't matter to me what graphics library you suggest. I would just like to know how to do this, or if there are actually a way to make a logical matrix out of 2 categorical variables and 1 numeric.

Thank you!